# Realm iOS: count the distinct objects in a collection

Tags: ios, swift, realm

What is the most efficient way to get the count of the unique values on a table?

For example:

```
fruitType
---------
banana
banana
apple
apple 
apple
```

bananas : 2
apples : 3

By using `fruitsCollection.distinct(by: ["fruitType"])` i can get the distinct values but not the count.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you could try something simple like this (assuming fruits are Strings, adjust accordingly to your object types):

```
let fruits = fruitsCollection.distinct(by: ["fruitType"])
var results = [String:Int]()
Set(fruits).forEach{ fruit in results[fruit] = (fruits.filter{$0 == fruit}).count }
print("---> results: \(results)")
```

or

```
let results: [String:Int] = Set(fruits).reduce(into: [:]) { dict, next in
            dict[next] = (fruits.filter{$0 == next}).count }

print("---> results: \(results)")
```

The `Set(fruits)` gives you the unique set of `fruit` names. The `filter{...}` gives you the count of each. The `forEach` or the `reduce` turns the results into a dictionary of key values.

Comment: Super good answer so +1 for you. However, for larger datasets this can be problematic as the device can be overwhelmed using high-level Swift functions like map, filter and reduce as *all* of the Realm data (which is often a LOT of data) is loaded into memory.

Comment: fair enough comment regarding memory usage. However, relying on nice words, "could be" and gut feeling 
is not the way assess the situation. Real results from some tests would 
be much better.

Comment: huh? I didn't use nice words 'could be' and I certainly don't code by gut feeling (after 45 years of coding, not my style. lol). I used the words *can be overwhelmed* purely because of the unknown size of the dataset. However, datasets *may* scale so it's better to code for that than have the app blow up intermittently at a later time. It's 100% fact that loading Realm objects with high level Swift functions defeats the lazy loading nature of Results and will occupy a lot more memory.

Answer (score 2):

@workingdog answer works very well but here's a more Realmy option. Something to keep in mind is that Realm Results objects are lazily loaded - meaning working with very large datasets has a low memory impact.

However, as soon high level Swift functions are used, that lazy-ness is lost and every object gobbles up memory.

For example, loading 50,000 Realm objects into a *Results* object doesn't have any significant memory impact - however, loading 50,000 objects into an *Array* could overwhelm the device as the objects loose their lazy-loading nature.

With this solution, we rely on Realm to present unique values and store them in Results (lazy!) then iterating over those we filter for matching objects (lazy) and return their count.

I created a FruitClass to hold the fruit types

```
class FruitClass: Object {
    @Persisted var fruitType = ""
}
```

and then to code

```
This is a very memory friendly solution

//get the unique types of fruit. results are lazy!
let results = realm.objects(FruitClass.self).distinct(by: ["fruitType"])

//iterate over the results to get each fruit type, and then filter for those to get the count of each
for fruit in results {
    let type = fruit.fruitType
    let count = realm.objects(FruitClass.self).filter("fruitType == %@", type).count
    print("\(type) has a count of \(count)")
}
```

and the results

```
apple has a count of 3
banana has a count of 2
orange has a count of 1
pear has a count of 1
```