# MongoDB Realm with nodejs memory leak issue

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, realm

We are using Realm with node.js in our product. The way we are using it is following:

```
const realmConfig = await Realm.open({
    path: "db_name.realm",
    schema: configurationList,
    schemaVersion: constant.appConfig.realm_schema
});

const data = clone(realmConfig.objects(schemaName));
realmConfig.close();
```

Even if we are closing the connection to avoid memory leak, it’s still using enormous memory (RealmObject and BSON).

I have attached memory snapshot here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Also, `clone` sounds suspicious…

Comment: @robertklep I'm facing an issue with using Realm with nodejs. I just found out that creating and closing connection increases RealmObject which you can see easily on the memory snapshot.

Comment: @robertklep Now it's creating an other issue. BSON in Realm is staking up the memory

Comment: Are you sure you're not just creating those references by your use of `clone()`?

Comment: I'm using clone as a function of JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(REALM_OBJ))

Comment: Why are you doing this `const data = clone(realmConfig.objects(schemaName));` at all? Can you explain the use case?

Comment: @Jay I'm using it because Realm returns Results { }  object. I want it in different format such as array of objects. That's why i'm using it.

Comment: A Results object acts very similar to an array so that task is (usually) unnecessary. Additionally, casting Results to an array in general can be hazardous to your app as it defeats the lazy-loading nature of Realm objects and can overwhelm the memory of the device. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72106916/realm-ios-count-the-distinct-objects-in-a-collection/72117505#72117505) which is Swift but the concept is the same. That's likely part, if not all, of the issue.

Comment: @Jay You are right. Clone is creating some memory leak as well as opening and closing the connection creates heavy memory leak by creating RealmObject in the background.  
For connection following thing fixed the issue:

const realm = new Realm({
    path: "db_name.realm",
    schema: configurationList,
    schemaVersion: constant.appConfig.realm_schema
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning the object creates memory leak moreover opening and closing the connection multiple time creates additional overhead to the memory and creates RealmObject in the background.

[image]