# How to make a wrapper for Realm that won't crash when used on different thread?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am creating a wrapper for Realm so I can test my app easily with mocks. This is the code:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import Realm

class RealmStorage: LocalStoring {
    private static let configuration: Realm.Configuration = {
        let schemaString = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "Realm Schema") as? String ?? ""
        let schema = UInt64(schemaString) ?? 1
        return Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: schema)
    }()
    private let category: String
    init(category: String) {
        self.category = category
    }
    
    func store<T: Object>(_ object: T) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm(configuration: RealmStorage.configuration)
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(object, update: .all)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Realm error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func update<T: Object>(_ object: T, value: Any?, for key: String) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm(configuration: RealmStorage.configuration)
            try realm.write {
                object.setValue(value, forKey: key)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Realm error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func retrieve<T: Object>(_ objectType: T.Type) -> [T] {
        
        guard let realm = try? Realm(configuration: RealmStorage.configuration) else {
            return []
        }
        
        let objects = realm.objects(objectType.self)
        return Array(objects)
    }
    
    func remove<T: Object>(_ objectType: T.Type,
                           where condition: @escaping (T) -> Bool) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm(configuration: RealmStorage.configuration)
            try realm.write {
                let objects = realm.objects(objectType.self).filter(condition)
                realm.delete(objects)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Realm error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func removeAll<T: Object>(_ objectType: T.Type) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm(configuration: RealmStorage.configuration)
            try realm.write {
                let objects = realm.objects(objectType.self)
                realm.delete(objects)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Realm error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried storing the `Realm` instance once  but it crashed when it is used in a background thread. With opening Realm object every time, it doesn't crash but now it runs slower. There is 1-2 seconds waiting time to do anything.

How do I make it not crash without opening Realm all the time? I was thinking to store all the `Objects` into an array and just use it instead of the Realm database. And write to database only when needed to sync the data from the array and database. But I was hesitant since that means I have two source of truth. And this may create bugs when the data between the array and database is not the same. Do you have any other idea?

Thanks.

Comment: A few thoughts: This `return Array(objects)` is likely a bad idea. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72106916/realm-ios-count-the-distinct-objects-in-a-collection/72117505#72117505). Then - *opening Realm all the time* - if this is local only then opening realm to read/write is a normal implementation. It's generally not a good idea to leave it 'open all the time'. Lastly... if I am reading it correctly, it *appears* the code is trying read/write to the app bundle? Take a look [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/realm-files/bundle-a-realm/)

Comment: @Jay Hi thanks for the comment. So you're saying that returning Results<T> is better memory wise? But will it be faster? I don't think we will have 50k objects in my app. They will always be cleaned daily since their lifetime is only 1 day (ie. any transaction that is more than 1 day ago will be removed). So memory won't be an issue. And no it is not trying to access app bundle. The bundle will just be used to get the schema version so the data can be migrated. BTW, do you have any guide to optimize using Realm?

Comment: Yes and yes, and will be much safer. "optimizing" is a big word and could apply in a variety of ways. If there's a specific coding example, please open another question, include what's not working as expected, your troubleshooting and we'll take a look. As far as this question goes "not crash all the time" is going to be tough to answer without troubleshooting details. If you're using a local realm, there should really never be a 1-2 second wait time for anything, so that leads me to believe some other code, outside the question, is causing the delays (aside from the Array issue as mentioned)

Comment: I see. But I actually don't want to leak the `Realm` to the Domain layer so it will eventually be mapped to an array of entities (eg. `[TransactionEntity]` which was mapped from `Results<TransactionObject>`). In fact, in the beginning I was designing the `RealmStorage` as one of the implementations of `BaseLocalStorage` which in turn has implementations of `KeyChainStorage`, `UserDefaultsStorage` and `InMemoryStorage`. All implementations will store and retrieve BaseEntity. But because I don't know how to design the mapper of `RealmObject` to/from `BaseEntity`, I just separate the `Realm`.

Comment: I suggest re-thinking the design. Mapping Realm objects to Arrays and/or using high level Swift functions is usually a bad idea. Realm Collections should stay Collections and here is no harm or downside in using Realm, Realm Collections and Realm objects throughout the app. Go back and take a look at the link in my first comment - that's good reason to not map to an Array. Not to mention overwhelming the device and significant performance hits. Also, there is likely no reason to have a BaseEntity - Realm objects are super flexible and having different objects represent data is Best Practice.

Comment: Oh and this code `let realm = try Realm(configuration: RealmStorage.configuration)` should never take 1-2 seconds. It's instant so there;s something else going on.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I have solved the problem. It turns out my `store(_:)` is not instant. So when I tried retrieving after storing, I couldn't find the object. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at either async [await constructs or actors](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swift-concurrency/). The idea there would be something like `try await your_await_write_function()` which in this case would write but await the completion of that before proceeding to the next section of code.

Comment: Well, I can't really use async/await since my target is iOS 11. But I use RxSwift though so I just use RxRealms for this. Anyway, I think we can close this. Do I need to delete the question or just answer it myself? It's a shame to lose this converstaion though.